# Is there an appropriate documentation tools following those criterias?

Tags: documentation

I actually search a good tool to make a documentation in a well and beautiful structured way. I recently discover bookstack, this is tools is very attractive but it's extremly difficult for me to install this type of tool. I don't have the knowledge for this.
So I search a equivalent(or a better) tool to bookstack.
So here's my criterias :

- The redaction interface should be able to allow picture and different font/style.
- The tools should allow to structure the documentation with for example part and subpart.
- The tool should be able to export each page or all page of my doc in html format AND pdf format.
- The tool should be free or have a free version containing all the criteria above.

I know that's a difficult task to find something like this, but I hope that one of members from this community could help me :) !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is many tools that fit to those criterias. But I choose TiddlyWiki because it was very simple. There is no installation nedded. Easy to handle and easy to understand.